# Criteria for convergence in Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> **Theorem 3.22:** $\sum a_n $ converges if and only if for every $\epsilon >0$ there is an integer $N$ such that $$ \left|\sum_{k=n}^m a_k \right | \leq \epsilon $$ if $ m \geq n \geq N $
>
> In particular, by taking $m=n$ becomes $$ \left|a_n \right | \leq \epsilon ~~~~~ (n\geq N)$$

However, the condition $ \left|a_n \right | \leq \epsilon $ is satisfied by $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$. Thus by the backward implication of the theorem, $\sum \frac{1}{n} $ should converge. However, as we know it, it does not.

Which part of the theorem have I misunderstood?

## Edit:

Would this be the correct interpretation of the theorem?
$$\sum a_n~converges \iff (\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists N \in \mathbb{N})\left( m \geq n \geq N \implies \left|\sum_{k=n}^m a_k \right | \leq \epsilon \right) $$

Comment: You should write if $$m>n\ge N$$ not $\le$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, we have $\frac1n<\varepsilon$ if $n$ is large enough. But you can't deduce from thath fact that$$\sum_{k=n}^m\frac1k<\varepsilon$$if $m\geqslant n$ and $m$ and $n$ are large enough.

Comment: Why you cant deduce?

Comment: How so? I am just using the particular backward implication of the theorem which states $$ \left|a_n \right | \leq \epsilon ~~~~~ (n\geq N) \implies \sum a_n ~converges$$. The antecedent is fulfilled by $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: You aren't interpreting the theorem correctly. Rudin says that a series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if a certain conditions holds. Then he asserts that **if** this condition holds, **then** $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. He never claims that this is an equivalence.

Comment: That section of the theorem IS NOT part of the if and only if. Only the first section is

Comment: Oh of course. Thank you very much

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Can you check the edit?

Comment: It's fine, except that you should add the word “converges” after $\sum a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

> If $m\ge n\ge N$ then $\left|\sum_{k=n}^ma_k\right|\le\epsilon$

means **for all** $m$,$n$ such that $m\ge n\ge N$. Taking $m=n$ is not equivalent to convergence.

Comment: Why is this not the correct reason? See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399418/theorem-3-22-from-baby-rudin?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

In other words, 
let $$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^na_k$$

the criteria is

$$\sum a_n\text{ converges } \iff (S_n) \text{ is Cauchy} \iff$$

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \;\; \exists N\in \Bbb N :$$

$$m>n\ge N \implies |S_m-S_n|<\epsilon$$